# cpp mysql InvalidArgumentException/anyone familiar with SQLString?

Tags: c++, mysql, invalidargumentexception

I'm using VS 2008. In a function call to a sql db table, I have

```
boost::scoped_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstmt( conn->prepareStatement(query) );

boost::scoped_ptr<sql::ResultSet> prow( pstmt->executeQuery() );
```

The query looks fine, if I copy it and run it in `mySql` workbench, I do get a record.

but `prow( pstmt->executeQuery()` threw `sql::InvalidArgumentException`

If I click continue, I get `Unhandled exception ... Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef6`

```
__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL ~basic_string()
    {   // destroy the string
    _Tidy(true);
    }
```

in a file called xstring.

The most relevant thing I've found is [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066599/mysql-cpp-connector-throwing-unknownexception-while-connecting/8087626#8087626)

Where the answer is to change `string` to `SQLString` for all the connection params, but I don't know what header file I need for `SQLString`?

or perhaps there are other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone who's used SQLString in cpp comment on what header file I need?

Answer (score 0):

set your resultSet to first row fetched after execution of query. like in MYSQL connector

ResultSet * resultSet;
(query execution code)
records return in resultSet
**resultSet->first();**
resultSet->getString("fieldName");

the the bold statement is missing then you would probably got this exception.